# htaccess: try to cut parameter from url, keep the other optional parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to cut a parameter from URLs but keep the others and I never know the value.

```
www.example.com/?useless=somevalue&foo=somevalue&bar=somevalue
to =>
www.example.com/?foo=somevalue&bar=somevalue

www.example.com/?useless=somevalue
to =>
www.example.com/

www.example.com/?foo=somevalue&bar=somevalue&useless=somevalue
to =>
www.example.com/?foo=somevalue&bar=somevalue
```

Comment: Another problem seems to be the actual value looks like `www.example.com/?useless=%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252Fproc%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252Fself%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252Fenviron` so how do I match these?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to remove a named query parameter from any position:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?useless=[^&]*&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: No actually doesn't work at all. No matter where the parameter is located.

Comment: It is working for on my Apache for every position of parameter. Most likely you have some local code/config issue that is causing this rule to not fire at all.

Comment: might be, it's in a CMS enviroment so there might be more.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, this single rule works for all 3 cases where parameter is first, last or in the middle. You have to keep this rule as first rule

Comment: Sorry, but I can't put it first cause than all the other stuff doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This rule won't impact anything else since it is just stripping a query parameter you don't want. Rest of the request URL remains untouched.

Answer (score 0):

What I Have right now:

If Parameter is in the middle

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)&useless=[0-9a-z_-]+&(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1&%2 [R=301,L]
```

If Parameter is the last one

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)&useless=[0-9a-z_-](.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1 [R=301,L]
```

If it's the first but has some following

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)?useless=[0-9a-z_-]+&(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

But can't figur out the condition and rule for if it's the only Parameter

Comment: Works unless the value of _useless_ is like `%25252525somethingsomething%2525`